# PHP/MySQL: Storing Multiple Values in Database Column

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

I have a form that allows you to input phone numbers. You can click a plus button and add more fields. I need to store all those values in the database but only have one column to do it.

With the phone number is also a type dropdown where you can select things like: Mobile, Home, and Work. So I need a way to pair the type and number together for each field, then combined all the pairs together. Then later on when I need the information, to be able to pull it all out and place all values into an array. Almost like encrypting and decrypting.

I was thinking of something like:

```
type:number;type:number;type:number;type:number;type:number;type:number
```

Being able to use explode and implode to encrypt and decrypt.

But how good is this? And I also have a search feature which searches for phone numbers. I imagine my way can't be easy for a search function to look through.

Comment: just don't do it.  It's not hard to create a new row for each phone number with a type column and the record id.  Doing it this way gains you nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say its a bad idea. If you planning to have limited types of numbers ie Home, Work, Mobile etcetera I suggest you to add columns for each number. Otherwise make a separate database table "phone_numbers" and relate this to your customer id or similar and add as many numbers you like. Searching will just be both faster and more easy to implement.

If you still need to store them in a single field then use php implode() and explode() as you suggest. In my cases where I do this I would use a character that my customers would rarely think of such as a pipe symbol "|" as a delimiter. Of course I need to use str_replace or such technique to filter out if my users accidentally has used it in the input but best if its a character seldom used.

Comment: Well the only issue I have with that is that I also have this same thing with emails, addresses, and websites. So that would mean I need to create a different table for each. I also can't add columns for each because I never know how many could be entered. One person could enter 10 numbers, another could enter 1.

Comment: One approach is to add two tables. One named users_data_types (holds types like "Phone number", "Email address" and "Website" and another one named users_data and then you can add as much user data you want in the users_data and just use the type you want.

Answer (score 2):

Searching is definitely not going to work. Especially if you use search for something like auto-completion, you want to be able to quickly select all numbers starting with certain digits.

There are two options: Add more columns or add a separate table for phone numbers containing just the type, number and id of the person.

Comment: @Tyler Dusty If searching is important, you really don't have any choice, you don't want to get and process all rows just to be able to search in your database. That might work with a few entries, but it really does not scale well.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Code :

```
$delimiter = "|";
if (isset($_POST['editfill_mobile'])) {
        $mobileArray = $_POST['editfill_mobile'];
        $replymobile = "";
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($mobileArray as $key => $value) {
            $i++;
            $replymobile .= $value;
            $replymobile .= $delimiter;
        }
    }
```

Store this $replymobile as is in the database column .

Eventually u may need to split the above string to parse data from it when you query the database  ....